# Creating boxplot from pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, keyerror

I am trying to create a boxplot from a single column of a pandas DataFrame I have in python, but it results in an error. I have already looked up the error and a suggestion is to check whether or not there are spaces in my column names. I have checked this, and there are not any. I will try to provide a MWE below, but this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow.

```
import pandas 

df = pandas.read_pickle(filepath)

df.head()
Out[14]: 
      T_Tot       T_R       T_I T_U Sorties
1  0.918826  0.899499         1   1    1187
2  0.875528  0.845891         1   1    1139
3  0.886373  0.865091  0.939394   1    1165
4  0.931139  0.914743         1   1    1234
5  0.914282  0.893873         1   1    1206

df.boxplot(column=['T_Tot'])
```

Which finally results in the error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['T_Tot'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try without the list: `column='T_Tot'` instead of `column=['T_Tot']`

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: also works perfectly fine for me, what pandas version are you using?

Comment: I found that the data type of the df was all set to 'object', after changing it to float it worked fine for me as well.